# C programming. Trying to loop trap a user into entering a positive number

Tags: c, stdio

Beginner here. I'm trying to trap a user into entering a positive number. However the while loop doesn't seem to be working for when the user enters and incorrect number.

Output:

```
Please enter a positive integer: -3
I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater than zero: why?
I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater than zero: -42
I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater than zero: 42
The positive integer was : 42
Press any key to continue....
```

Code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
void clear_keyboard_buffer(void);
int main()
{
    int k;
    printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    if (k > 0)
    {
        clear_keyboard_buffer();
        printf("The positive integer was: %d ", k);

    }
    while (k<=0)
    {
        printf("I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater than zero: ");
        scanf("%d", &k);
        return 0;
    }
}

void clear_keyboard_buffer(void)
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try making an else statement for your if (k > 0) then put your while block inside that else.

Comment: @CurseStacker like this?else
 {
  while (k <= 0)
  {
   printf("I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater than zero: ");
   scanf("%d", &k);
   return 0;
  }
 }

Comment: Code does not match "Output:".

Comment: Remove return 0 from while loop and add after while

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read the documentation (e.g. of [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) etc...) And test the result of `scanf`. Consider also using `fgetc` to read a single character. Be aware of buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think it's easiest to show you some code that does what you want, along with some comments about why you should do it that way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) /* note the void here, it says "no parameters"! */
{
    int k;

    /* here we don't use printf() because there is no formatting to do */
    fputs("Please enter a positive integer: ", stdout);

    scanf(" %d", &k); /* note the space, it consumes any whitespace */

    while (k < 1)
    {
        fputs("I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater "
                "than zero: ", stdout);
        scanf(" %d", &k);
    }

    printf("You entered `%d'\n", k);

    return 0;
}
```

Still you *should* check the return value of `scanf()` for production quality code because there *could* be errors (e.g. the user entering something that isn't a number ...)

That being said, for really *reliable* user input, I'd suggest to abandon `scanf()` altogether and just use e.g. `fgets()` to read a line of input (whatsoever) and then parse yourself. `strtol()` could come handy ...

Just to give you an idea what I'm talking about, here's a very simple but reliable solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int readInt(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    int input;
    char *endptr;

    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);

    /* strip off "end of line" characters */
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\r\n")] = 0;

    input = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);

    /* sanity check, only accept inputs that can be wholly parsed as
     * an integer
     */
    if (buf[0] == 0 || *endptr != 0) input = -1;

    return input;
}

int main(void)
{
    int k;

    fputs("Please enter a positive integer: ", stdout);

    k = readInt();

    while (k < 1)
    {
        fputs("I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer greater "
                "than zero: ", stdout);
        k = readInt();
    }

    printf("You entered `%d'\n", k);

    return 0;
}
```